# Collect all Log.d from class and save it into SDCard

Tags: android, logging

Hey is it possible in Android to collect all Log.d from one class and keep on appending it and save it into SDCard ?

For example :

```
Class Android {

    private final static String TAG = "hello";

    public void abcd(){
    Log.d(TAG, "it went into abcd method");
    }

    public void efgh(){
    Log.d(TAG, "it went into efgh method");
    }

       /*Here collect all above LOGS and write to file in SDCard*/

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all logs with the `logcat` command. You can try something like:

```
public static void printLog(Context context){
    String filename = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + File.separator + "my_app.log";
    String command = "logcat -d *:V";

    Log.d(TAG, "command: " + command);

    try{
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        try{
            File file = new File(filename);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                writer.write(line + "\n");
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can get more information about `logcat` here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: Thanks Addrallyn, But i require only particular logs with TAG - "hello". Is that possible with above your code ?

Comment: You can specify a tag : logcat -s "hello"

Comment: Yes i got that Addrallyn, I am trying, will let u know if it works.

Comment: Addrallyn, Any Idea where the file is saved in SDCard ? I couldn't find the location

Comment: On my phone, it is saved in /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.****.****/files/my_app.log. You can specify a new path by modifying the second line.

Comment: why do you want to write it by yourself? why not to use Logger instead?

Comment: Addrallyn, Thanks for your help. I am now creating a new directory and saving there. But "logcat -d *:V" works which gives complete log, but "logcat -s *hello"; won't work...Any idea? Are you missing something ?

Comment: Try `logcat -s hello` (without '*').

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Log class and do that yourself. But is it really required for your purposes?

Comment: Rajeev, This is useful when you want to access some particular logs in a scenario where u are actually travelling or checking something classes related to GPS navigation where u don't have DBMS with u and all those handy log applications on Google Play doesn't work like u want so easiest is to track all those logs and write it into file

Answer (score 0):

no, Log.* methods write to the console, however you can use Logger http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger.html and a FileHandler

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add logs with tag name and

```
logcat -s <Tagname>
```

Is not working for you then you can do this trick

```
//... Brtle 's code..(accepted one )
    file.createNewFile();
       FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
         while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
             if(line.contains("TAG_NAME")){ // Trick :-)
                writer.write(line + "\n");
               }
             }
```